# How to check whether a json contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript array containing JSON Object like this:-

```
var data :[{
         name:"ABC",
         categories:[{
                     name:"XYZ",
                     categories:[{
                           .
                            .
                             .
                              N
                        }]
              }]
}]
```

I want to iterator in this array and wanna check whether `categories[]` present or not and `Categories[]` have any value or not , If yes then insert the data inside it

EG:

```
var mydata:[];
 mydata.push({name:"MNP",Categories:[]});
```

I want to insert this data inside categories

Comment: Your JSON structure itself seems to be weird. Consider modifying it.

Comment: the json is an array, not an object. but to save things to a variable you have to use `var x = y;` with `=` and not `:`

Comment: @mtizziani I can't use = in my code because this json is  part of my application based on  UI5 .  My JSON is absolutely  correct.

Comment: @ChandrasekarG its seems  to be weird  but I  think no need to  modified it . This JSON is as per the requirement of the application

Comment: This has nothing to do with UI5. Even in UI5, `var something: value` is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is a sample object containing 1 element is text and one element is an array
var object = {smapleA: 'some text', sampleB : ['stringArray']};

// init a var to save the status (intial it must be false)
var containsArray = false;

// go over each element in the object with this loop definition
for(let key in object){
   // for be clean check if object.key realy exists 
   if(object.hasOwnProperty(key){

     // here you check if the current element is an Array
     if(Array.isArray(object[key])){

       // set containsArray variable to true
       containsArray = true;
     }
   }
}

console.log(containsArray);
```